# bootstrap accordion collapses in chrome on back click not on mozilla

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, firefox

I have a bootstrap accordion like this in my rails app.

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-group">
          <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
              Collapsible Group Item #1
            </a>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px; ">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
             s1
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-group">
          <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
              Collapsible Group Item #2
            </a>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px; ">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
              s2
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-group">
          <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
              Collapsible Group Item #3
            </a>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-body in collapse">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="proceed_to_order">Proceed</button></div>
  </div>
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kXTc6/29/).

So when I click, I am carrying these values to the next page (which I am unable to put in the fiddle). So In Mozila browser when I click back in the browser the last accordion when I had opened and clicked on proceed remains open. But for Chrome when I click back, all the accordion is automatically are closed which I don't want.

Is there any work around for this?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

replace with:

```html
<div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px; ">
    <div class="accordion-inner">
       s3
    </div>
</div>
```

in third number of accordion group..